# Error in png(filename = mypath) : png() In addition: Warning messages: 1: In png(filename = mypath) :

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I want multiple plot using for loop in R
my code is below...but it's not working following the massage

Error in png(filename = mypath) : png()
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png(filename = mypath) :
2: In png(filename = mypath) : opening device failed

what is the problem?

plot_name <- c(1:400) # 그래프 파일명 순번

```
for(i in 1:2) { 
  start <- 1+(i-1)*40000 
  end <- (1+i-1)*40000
  mypath <-  file.path("C:/Users/DS266/Desktop/calibration/graph", 
                       paste("plot_", plot_name[i], ".png", sep = "")) 
  par(mar=c(5,5,5,5)+10, las=1) 
  png(file = mypath, width = 1000, height = 600, unit="px") 
  plot(df$time[start:end],  
       df$flow_3[start:end], 
       type = 'b', 
       pch = 6, # △
       cex = 0.5,
       col = 6, 
       xlab = "",
       ylab = "",
       ylim = c(0,6),
       axes = T,
       ann = F)
  lines(x = df$time[start:end], 
        y = df$flow_2[start:end],
        type = 'b',
        pch = 2, 
        cex = 0.5,
        col = 2) 
  
  lines(x = df$time[start:end], 
        y = df$flow_3[start:end],
        type = 'b',
        pch = 3, 
        cex = 0.5,
        col = 3) 
  lines(x = df$time[start:end], 
        y = df$flow_4[start:end],
        type = 'b',
        pch = 4, 
        cex = 0.5,
        col = 4) 
  lines(x = df$time[start:end],
        y = df$flow_5[start:end],
        type = 'b',
        pch = 5,
        cex = 0.5,
        col = 5)
  lines(x = df$time[start:end],
        y = df$flow_7[start:end],
        type = 'b',
        pch = 7,
        cex = 0.5,
        col = 7)
  
  par(new = TRUE)
  
  plot(df$time[start:end],
       df$rainfall[start:end],
       type = 'h',
       col = "blue",
       axes = F,
       ann = F,
       ylab = "",
       ylim = c(4,0))
  
  axis(side = 4, at = c(4:0))
 
  mtext("Date(MM:DD)", side = 1, adj = 0.5, padj = 3)
  mtext("Flow(CMS)", side = 2, adj = 0.5, padj = -3)
  mtext("Rainfall(mm)", side = 4, adj = 0.5, padj = 3)
  
  legend("left",
         c("No.2","No.3","No.4","No.5","No.6","No.7","Rainfall"),
         col = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,"blue"),
         pch = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,15))
  plot_title <- paste(df$time[start],"~",df$time[end])
  title(main = plot_title)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Print and check the values of `mypath`.

Comment: Like you said, check the value of mypath and edit my code. But error message sitll appear,,,"In png(file = mypath) : opening device failed". I have no idea what the problem is....

Comment: My guess was an invalid file path (e.g., there might be no folder "calibration"). If that is not the case, I have no further guesses. And your example is not reproducible, so I can't test. Start debugging: Can you open a `png` device at all?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I solved this problem like above code. But, another problem is appear. No secondary y-axis labels appear in the graph....what can i do for it?